# chef windows_package throws error: Option installer_type must be a kind of [String]! You passed :custom

Tags: chef-infra

We have the following recipe in our cookbook:

```
windows_package "application" do
  source package_name
  installer_type :custom
  options "/q"
  action :install
  only_if { ::File.exists?("#{filepath}\\#{install_dir}\\setup.exe") }
end
```

We are trying to install the .exe file. However, chef is throwing the following error:

### Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed

Option installer_type must be a kind of [String]!  You passed :custom.

Can someone help me with identifying what is causing the issue.

chef client version is 11.14.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `installer_type` property wasn't used back in Chef 11.14.6, we only supported MSIs. You can dig up an old version of the `windows` cookbook which had the out-of-core support for custom and nsis installers. For the record you are using a version of Chef that is over a year out of date by now. Not recommended.

Comment: Thank you @coderanger, that worked. I added the 'windows' cookbook in my dependencies and that resolved the issue.

Yes, 11.14 is an old version. We are going to upgrade the chef version in all our instances shortly.